# IE 11 crashes when using web worker with large data in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, internet-explorer, web-worker

I have an application that is crashing in Internet Explorer 11 when i navigate from 1 page to another.
I have 2 pages, A viewer page and a listing page. the viewer page has a web worker which starts downloading images on the server as soon as the page is loaded. Everything works fine if i stay on the page and let the images download. the problem occurs when i click on the home link in the viewer page to go back to my listing page. what I am doing is when the viewer page is loaded, I immediately click on the home link to go back to the list page without letting the web worker finish its job. it crashes IE 11 most of the times. all the other browsers navigate to the other page without any issues.

I am also terminating the worker when i click on the home link. but the application still freezes.

Is there a way i can stop IE from crashing on navigation?

PS: there are a lot of Ajax requests happening in the page on load which access the session object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by setting the Controller with the following attribute

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

this was happening because the session was getting locked on multiple requests.

here's the [link](http://www.allpaul.com/post/2013/03/30/Disable-Session-State-on-AJAX-Called-MVC-Controllers-) to the article that explains this

Comment: http://www.allpaul.com/post/2013/03/30/Disable-Session-State-on-AJAX-Called-MVC-Controllers- is a dead link.  It seems www.allpaul.com is down.